# How to add UIView to the CorePlot view?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a UIView for CorePlot and I want to add UIView under the plot as a subview. I have tried this:

`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:_viewTable];`

But it doesnt work. How can I make it work?

EDIT:

My Storyboard:

[image]

Green - firstPieChartView (CorePlot view)

Red - UIview with tableView

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self.firstPieChartView addSubview:_viewTable];
  [self.firstPieChartView bringSubviewToFront:_viewTable];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add subviews to a Core Plot hosting view. The iOS hosting view applies a flip transform to its children so Core Plot can share drawing code with the Mac version. Instead of making your view a subview of the hosting view, make them siblings (i.e., children of the same parent view).

Answer (score 0):

You are bringing the view to front by this, not adding it as a subview. First you have to use:

```
[self.view addSubview:yourSubview];
```

--in order to add it. Then you can bring it to front, if you're overlaying it with other subviews.

Comment: Are you adding it to the CorePlot view or `self.view`? There's a big difference.

Comment: Then in order to help you I need to see more code. I can't diagnose the problem like this...

Comment: Hm, try bringing the subview to front **AFTER** you set up the graph. When it is all set up, then bring it to front. Not in `viewDidLoad`.